# How do I use the Video module with Colorbox?

Tags: 7, files, javascript

I am using the Video module, and I want to show videos on Colorbox. I have also found a [patch](http://drupal.org/node/1155628) for that, but I don't understand something.

I am using the most recent versions.

- Colorbox: 7.x-2.3
- Video: 7.x-2.9

Comment: What exactly don't you understand. You said, "but I don't understand something" without saying what.

Answer (score 3):

I dont know to use video module but can open a video in colorbox easily with  [Video Embed Field](http://drupal.org/project/video_embed_field). Just create a content type with field as Video Embed Field and in the manage display tab Select the format as 'Preview with Colorbox'.